# Android: java.net.HttpURLConnection - does IOException indicate failure to connect to the internet or something else?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I guess this could double as a peer review request.  Given the following:

```
// This file is protected under the KILLGPL.
// For more information, visit http://www.lukeleber.github.io/KILLGPL.html
//
// Copyright (c) Luke Leber <LukeLeber@gmail.com>

package com.lukeleber.util.network;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;

import com.lukeleber.util.BuildConfig;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public final class Connectivity
{
    /// @internal debugging tag
    private final static String TAG = Connectivity.class.getName();

    /// The default URL for tests that connect to the internet
    public final static String DEFAULT_INTERNET_TEST_URL = "http://www.google.com";

    /// The default time-out for tests that connect to the internet
    public final static int DEFAULT_INTERNET_TIMEOUT_MILLIS = 1000;

    /// Uninstantiable
    private Connectivity()
    {

    }

    public static boolean isConnectedToInternet(final Context context, final String testURL,
                                                final int timeoutMillis)
    {
        /// Debugging check only - provides a slightly stricter policy than the android runtime,
        /// as this check catches 100% of the erroneous calls to this method whereas the built-in
        /// routine will only catch calls that actually make it to the blocking HTTP connection.
        /// As this check is omitted from release builds, we can only hope that the sources were
        /// at least compiled and ran in debug mode prior to shipping.
        if(BuildConfig.DEBUG && Looper.myLooper().equals(Looper.getMainLooper()))
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "blocking method called on UI thread");
        }
        if(context == null)
        {
            if(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            {
                Log.w(TAG, "Null value for 'context'");
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("context == null");
        }
        if(testURL == null)
        {
            if(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            {
                Log.w(TAG, "Null value for 'testURL'");
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("testURL == null");
        }
        if(timeoutMillis < 0)
        {
            if(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            {
                Log.w(TAG, "Illegal value for 'timeoutMillis': " + timeoutMillis);
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("timeoutMillis < 0");
        }
        final String[] requiredPermissions = new String[]
        {
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
                Manifest.permission.INTERNET
        };
        final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        for(final String permission : requiredPermissions)
        {
            if(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED != pm.checkPermission(permission, packageName))
            {
                Log.w(TAG, "Unable to check internet connectivity: Permission " +
                        permission + " is not granted.");
                return false;
            }
        }
        final ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if(cm == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected())
        {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try
            {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(testURL).openConnection();
                    connection.setConnectTimeout(1);
                connection.connect();
                return connection.getResponseCode() == Constants.HTTP.HTTP_RESPONSE_OK;
            }
            catch(final MalformedURLException murle)
            {
                if(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                {
                    Log.w(TAG, "testURL is an invalid URL", murle);
                }
                throw (IllegalArgumentException)
                        new IllegalArgumentException("testURL is not a valid URL")
                                .initCause(murle);
            }
            catch (final IOException e)
            {
                /// todo: research why this might happen
                /// Maintainer,
                /// Is it better to return false (assume the internet is unreachable)
                /// or to throw an exception (we don't know if the internet is reachable)?
                if(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Unknown error", e);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if(connection != null)
                {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Does an IOException 100% indicate a failure in connectivity - or are there any subtleties that aren't documented by the JDK docs?

This code has three results:

1) Returns true - the app has internet connectivity
2) Returns false - the app does not have internet connectivity
3) Throws an exception - something is not right and as such the result could be either true or false.

What does everyone think?

Comment: IOException is parent to a large number of exceptions. from protocol, to interrupted i/o, all of ssl related errors, unknown host (which can happen on a network disconnected from the internet) or no route to host, timeouts, ... and more

Comment: Granted, so is it safe to assume in the presence of such an exception that connectivity failure is definitively the cause?  (Or catastrophic local failure).

Comment: @LukeA.Leber Obviously not.

Comment: Could you please provide an example otherwise?

Comment: a typical case of error while still having proper connectivity is the case of the SSL exception caused by the wrong date being set on the device.

Comment: I see.  So there is not a black and white answer to my initial question.  I do hate gray areas. Thanks for your knowledge.  *Would you recommend trying to pick the cases apart or throwing an exception or simply returning false?

Comment: the server you are trying to reach could be temporarily unavailable, too, or you could be on one of those networks that will not let you connect to some servers.

Comment: it really depends on what you need that info for, and how bad it is if you say no when it really should be yes

Comment: The info is needed for a general purpose check that could be trivial or 'fire the missiles' depending on how its used.  I'd like it to be bullet proof as its going in my permanent utility library.  By the way, if you move this into an answer I'll accept it.